# How can I enter a default value for a field, based on another field's value in MYSQL using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a db called Products

product_id Primary  int(11)         No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT
product_cat_id  int(11)
product_title   varchar(150)

I would like a field call product_directory as Varchar(20) to be a string version of product_id

How would I do this in mySQL via phpMyAdmin.  Any help will be appreciated

Comment: *I would like a field call product_directory as Varchar(20) to be a string version of product_id* Use generated column.

Comment: Thanks Akina, I need to do this within the structure if possible preferably using default of product_directory to point to the product_id field.  I dont know how I would do this and if its at all posssible

Comment: Please explain why you need in field copy. MySQL's datatype is soft - if you use integer value in string context (for example, as an argument of CONCAT function) then it will be automatically converted. Also you may convert it explicitly using CAST function in retrieving query. So it makes no sense - to have string-type field which stores a copy of existing numeric field. Maybe you'll describe your task more detailed - why, for what?

Comment: Thanks Akina, yes your right, I will do this when retrieving query. That makes more sense.